# Capturing the TAB key in Gmail and other sites that blocks the capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, jquery-events, preventdefault

Using `preventDefault()` on a `keydown` works for all keys **except** the tab key on certain sites like Gmail.

1. Why is this the case? What is special about the tab key -- shouldn't it be treated the same as any other `keypress`?
2. How can I block the tab key from cycling through elements in Gmail?

Here is the Greasemonkey (JS with jQuery) code I'm currently using:

```
$("body.editable.LW-avf").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 9){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Anything other than <kbd>tab</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>a</kbd>) works - the `keypress` is stopped. How can I capture the tab key?

Comment: Tried a variety of things and can block that tab almost everywhere but the editable `<body>`.  Have you considered switching email clients? (^_^)  Scripting for Google sites is a chore.  Good luck!

Comment: PS:  The tab key isn't being treated the same way, on Gmail, by design.  Gmail JS is deliberately doing something with the tab, your technique works on normal sites.  (Figuring out exactly how Gmail is wired into the tab, is proving less than straightforward.)

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is probably already using `preventDefault` to redefine the event handler, since it is not using `tabindex`. In that case, you would need to override the definition of `preventDefault`:

```
Event.prototype.preventDefault = function(){}
```